# Is it a bad practice to use divs for styling purposes?

Tags: html, semantics

I've seen lately a lot of discussions about this new concept called *oocss* and I was wondering if it is a bad practice to wrap your main tags in `div`s only for styling/page layout purposes.

I'm asking this because I see some frameworks like **Twitter Bootstrap** use such a method.

What are the implications of such a markup from a semantic and accessibility point of view?

For example:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span4">
      <nav class="nav">...</nav>
    </div>
    <div class="span8">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-large">...</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

instead of

```
<div class="menu">
  <nav class="nav">...</nav>
  <a href="#" class="bttn">...</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't layouting exactly what divs are ment for?

Comment: @Vlad Piersec In future don't forget to add examples for better understanding...

Comment: @BlackCobra OK I edited this. Sorry I thought it was clear enough...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's fine. HTML is a "mark-up language", and mark-up involves styling. Besides, everyone does it. Many of the fluid multi-column layouts rest precisely on this approach.

Comment: If _everybody does it_ doesn't make it implicitly good.

Remember that for a long while people used tables for layout. It was a common practice at the time.

Comment: @VladPiersec when you defer to well established widget frameworks like Bootstrap and jQuery UI like you already alluded to.... if their practices include multiple wrappers as they do, you can't really go far wrong following their best practices

Comment: @VladPiersec I agree that widespread usage doesn't ensure that this is good practice. My implicit point, however, is that many people use this approach because it works well when it's adaptive (as, indeed, were tables regarded at a certain point in the evolution of HTML theory). I abhor redundant double wrapping, but if the second wrapping achieves something helpful then I see no point objecting on purist grounds.

Answer (score 0):

Using unnecessary `divs` is not a good idea... if the HTML codes in the second box is enough to do everything that you want or need to do then don't use extra `divs`... secondly, HTML codes in the second box is much clear and shorter then the codes in the first box... if you keep your codes clean, short and formatted, it will help you a lot when you want or need to update your code in future...

Comment: I'm not talking about this particular case. I'm talking about the concept. The code from both boxes can work if I use proper styling.

And if I want to update the code in the future there are both advantages and disadvantages with these styles. I'm not talking about maintainability. 

I want to know details on semantics and accessibility.